# How to root without executing unknown binary? (Open source/adb shell root?)

Tags: rooting, adb, shell, open-source

I have an Android 6.0 phone that has not received updates in a year.  It has likely dozens of security holes that allow one to gain `root` access.  I wish to do this in order to remove pre-installed bloatware system apps and change system config files.  However, all methods known to me involve running some closed source rooting tool that may very well contain a trojan or other malware.

**What open-source (or ideally, type-in `adb shell` command list) method is there to root an Android phone not patched in the last year?**

Of course, if a rooting tool is open source I would need to build it myself to be sure - so that would involve *much* more work than executing a script or entering shell commands

Comment: As matter of fact, you cannot alter the `/system` partition via adb, and hence cannot root.

Comment: Every Android device has different methods to root it, in some cases a security vulnerability is used, but this is becoming less and less common as it is only a device by device case. There is no generic vulnerability to exploit to gain root. The best way to root is to unlock the bootloader via official methods, install a custom recovery like TWRP, and flash a root method like Magisk or SuperSU.

Comment: There are a couple of implementations of the futex exploit (e.g. Towelroot) floating around that you could try to compile and run on your device, assuming it's vulnerable. I haven't tried them, but [this repository](https://github.com/timwr/CVE-2014-3153) has a project made to be built with the Android NDK. You'd probably want to use the privilege escalation to then help you install something permanent, though.

Comment: Very legit concern, but at the same time if a way is easy enough and open-sourced then patching against it is all too easy as well. We've pretty much run out of such exploits since Android 4.x.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Why can't I `remount -o rw /system` via `adb shell` if I achieve `root` in this shell (by the exploit I am looking for)?  Is there some extra protection by container (cgroups/namespaces) and/or `chroot`?

Comment: @acejavelin That's why I wrote that I haven't received a patch in a year. Since then dozens of security flaws in Android 6.0 have been publicised and fixed - common to all of these systems, unless they are special hardened variants.

Comment: @eldarerathis Thanks, something like this (a POC for a root exploit) is exactly what I was looking for. However, the referenced towelroot is so old that it was probably completely fixed in the 2014-06-03 patch ([this one?](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e9c243a5a6de0be8e584c604d353412584b592f8)).

Comment: @Ned64 If you are able to gain temporary root privileges, then you may also be able to remount `/system` as read-write and install a permanent `su` binary. While I'm not aware of any special protection, you may want to stay alert because of `SELinux`. Moreover, certain devices have the ability to automatically restore a known safe `/system` partition in case of changes.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Thanks. So, let's bring on the exploit!